# Is my assumption in levy bending plates right?

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, trigonometric-series

I have a coding project where I have to solve an equation that could be simplified as:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{m} \sin(i*x)*f(C_i)=0,
 \forall x \in [0,\pi],
$$

where I have to find all the $C_i$ (not $x$), $C_i$ does not depend of $x$ only of $i$, and because of that I assumed that I hat to solved $f(C_i)=0$ equations, but my teacher said that I was wrong and to get the $m$ equations needed I have to substitute the first equation with $m x$ (excluding the trivial $\pi$ and $0$). And then solve.

After programing, for my surprise, I got the same solutions.

Is my solution valid?

Since maybe i´m not the best explainer, i put you in context, I have to program a levy plate deformation solver. the problem is rule by this equation:

$
u_z(x,y)= \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sin({\pi ix\over a})*(A_i\cosh({\pi iy\over a})+B_i\sinh({\pi iy\over a})+{\pi iy\over a}(C_i\cosh({\pi iy\over a})+D_i\sinh({\pi iy\over a}))+f_i(y)), a\in \mathbb{R}
$

It must follow the following the boundary conditions

$
\forall x,\in [0,a],\ and\  y=\pm{b\over 2},\ \frac{\partial^2 u_z}{\partial y^2}+\nu\frac{\partial^2 u_z}{\partial x^2}=0, \ and \ \frac{\partial^3 u_z}{\partial y^3}+(2-\nu)\frac{\partial^3 u_z}{\partial x^2\partial y}=0
$

After playing a bit with the equations you end up with 4 equations similar to the simplify version above. Since x is linearly independence of the coefficients $A_i\ B_i\ C_i\ D_i $, i think just by solving the 4 $ f(C_i)$  for each i is sufficient enough, but maybe I'm wrong. I tried expanding the $sin(nx)$ series but I lack mathematical knowledge to follow that route. Because of that I lack the knowledge to proof me or my teacher wrong. When I asked my teacher about this his explanation didn't seem to give a hint of why I was wrong, so I write in their forum to get a certain answer because withe the two versions of the solver I have, it doesn't matter what I do to prove me wrong (increasing m, $f_i(y)$

Thanks beforehand

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: If I ask you to solve $Ax+By = 0$ for nonzero constants $A$ and $B$, the boring/useless solution is $x = y = 0$.  Can you find another solution that actually tells you something about $A$ and $B$?  Your teacher is telling you to find this other solution (or possibly other solutions, since I don't know how exciting $f$ is).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you completely but we have that if all $f(C_i) =0$ then the expression is trivially $0$, however if there's a solution such that $f(C_i) \neq 0$ for any $i$ then with your way (if I understood it) won't find it.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Since the $x \mapsto \sin (kx)$ functions are linearly independent over $[0, \pi]$, the only solutions are $f(C_i) = 0$.

Comment: I don't think the problem is explained clearly enough to know what you are trying to do or what you are doing.